# Playing mp4 files using openmax AL framework

Tags: android, mp4, openmax

How to play mp4 files using openmax AL framework ans android buffer queue?
I suppose android buffer queue only fed .ts data

Here is the code:

```
XADataLocator_AndroidBufferQueue loc_abq = { XA_DATALOCATOR_ANDROIDBUFFERQUEUE, NB_BUFFERS };

 XADataFormat_MIME format_mime = {
            XA_DATAFORMAT_MIME, XA_ANDROID_MIME_MP2TS, XA_CONTAINERTYPE_MPEG_TS };

 XADataSource dataSrc = {&loc_abq, &format_mime};
```

and then creating media player object.

But its giving me an error as cannot create player with XA_DATALOCATOR_ANDROIDBUFFERQUEUE data source that is not fed MPEG-2 TS data.

Comment: Look at ndk samples. There is an example

Comment: I am curious if anyone found solution. I started looking it very recently and even in current source only supported format is MPEG-2 TS. Is there anyway to play mp4 or OpenMAX is not good choice on Andorid and stick to MediaCodec?

Comment: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/native-codec